# In ruby on rails, why some controller does not work in the production environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to RoR and using RoR 4.1

I generate a model in the development; everything works just fine.

But how can I make the model works for other environment like 'production'?

I checked, but don't know where to enable a model works for other environments?

Comment: Please give more details about your problem, we can't help you with such information like that.

Comment: Did you check server logs? any errors? Did you run migrations?

Comment: you are right, Bongs, I forgot to migrate the DB. Could you move the comment to answer and I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably wrongly named you controller class and filename. Please remember Rails uses conventions to load classes from files. Make sure your controller filename and classname are a match. Post the names here if you can't fix it.